# Jquery ajax filter checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, checkbox

I making a country/department/city filter with checkboxes and ajax calls.

[image]

When i select a country Argentina for example all the departments and cities are selected and when i select a department all cities inside that department are selected. This is working fine but when i clic Argentina it calls again the ifChanged tigger for all departments and cities.

```
$('input').on('ifChanged', function(event){
   // Ajax call
});
```

So when the event is tiggered the ajax call is executed lot of times because is tiggered again and again until it finished.

I need to call the ajax function when the last element in trigger is complete, is this possible? Thanks

Comment: maybe fuilter by `if(event.target!==this)return;`

Comment: Where i have to put that if condition? Is not working

Answer (score 0):

You could select the last checkbox/input using the jquery :last selector

```
$('input:last').on('ifChanged', function(event){
   // Ajax call
});
```